# Override dbt's default incremental strategy for Postgres

Tags: postgresql, dbt

I have a dbt model that populates a table, foo. foo has a column, id, that is referenced as a foreign key by a different table, bar.

Sometimes my upstream data source changes a different column of foo, baz. I'd like to be able to update the value of foo.baz without changing the value of foo.id, so that my end users see up-to-date data about foo. Unfortunately, Postgres throws an error during dbt's default "delete then insert" strategy because I can't delete a foreign key from foo that's referenced by bar.

Does anyone know how to customize dbt's incremental modeling strategy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so using [this](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues/5467) as inspiration, I solved with:

```
{# Overrides default postgres update strategy #}
{%- macro default__get_delete_insert_merge_sql(target, source, unique_key, dest_columns) -%}
    {%- set dest_cols_csv = get_quoted_csv(dest_columns | map(attribute="name")) -%}
    {{log('target is ' ~ target.identifier, True)}}
    insert into {{ target }} ({{ dest_cols_csv }})
    (
       select {{ dest_cols_csv }}
       from {{ source }}
    )
    {%- if unique_key is not none -%}
        on conflict (
            {%- for key in unique_key -%}
                {{key}}
            {%- if not loop.last -%}, {%- endif -%}
            {%- endfor -%}
        )
        do update set {% if target.identifier != 'customers' %} 
            custom_data = EXCLUDED.custom_data,
            {% endif %} _fivetran_synced = EXCLUDED._fivetran_synced
    {%- endif %}
    ;
{%- endmacro %}
```